# How to parse an pointer in string form to int pointer in C

Tags: c, linux

I passed an int pointer as an argument to execv(...), which is now in string form in the other program. How do I parse that string back to a pointer array. For example, argv[2] is "0x7ffeec636875". How do I parse it to a int pointer so I can use it?

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
        int *matrix1Start = argv[2];
        printf("pointer: %p", argv[2]);
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can't. Pointers are only valid within the process and can't be directly used in other processes. That is, each process has a seperate address space.

Comment: You need to use some sort of interprocess comminication (IPC). File, shared memory, socket, pipe, etc.

Comment: Parsing it as a hex number is easy enough, but serves no purpose.  What do you intend to do with a pointer value from a different process?  It's useless.  You need to pass the *data*, not the address it happened to be stored at.

Comment: The 2 processes are parent and child (using fork()), would that make a difference?

Comment: execv() replaces the virtual address space (irrespective of whether the process is parent/child), so the data stored at the address would no longer be present in the memory of the execv'd program.

Comment: I see. I'll try to write the data into shared memory then. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

In a system with memory virtualization (e.g. any modern general purpose computer), each process has its own address space. What one process has at address `0x7ffeec636875` is completely unrelated to what another process has at that same address.

Since pointers refer to a location in a process's address space, it's useless to pass them to a different process (except in very exceptional circumstances you would have mentioned if applicable).

This is not a suitable way to achieve inter-process communication (IPC).

Comment: _Unless_ the child process explicitly binds something at a specific address via `mmap`, `shmat` and the like.

Comment: @DYZ That's already covered by my answer ("except in very exceptional circumstances you would have mentioned if applicable").

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume that `argv[2]` is indeed a string representation of a pointer created with `sprintf` or a similar function (e.g., "0x7ffeec636875"). Then you can use `sscanf`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *s = argv[2];
    int *p;
    sscanf(s, "%p", &p);
    printf("%p\n", p);
}
```

The resulting pointer `p` makes sense after `fork` but before `execv`. In general, it does not make sense after `execv`, unless you use `mmap` or `shmat` or a similar function in the child process that binds external object to a specific virtual address.

If, however, `argv[2]` is a result of a typecast (`(char*)p`), then what you want if not doable.

Comment: The OP is doing `execlp(..., matrix1Start, ..., 0)` or equivalent. Even if we assumed that worked, using `sscanf` won't help.

Comment: The OP wants to know how to convert `argv[2]` (which is clearly a `char*`) to an `int*`. `sscanf` is precisely the right tool for that.

Comment: Except it was made `char*` through a typecast, not through the use of `snprintf`. The inverse of `(char*)p` is not `sscanf`, it's `(int*)p`

Comment: @ikegami How do you know? There is nothing in their code to support your assumption. `argv[2]` may become `"0x7ffeec636875"` only through `sprtintf`, not through a typecast.

Comment: Re "*How do you know?*", I can only go by what the OP said, which is that they passed an `int*` to `exec`. I don't have any reason to believe the OP is mistaken about this. /// `args[2]` is `"0x7ffeec636875"` as shown by `printf("pointer: %p", argv[2]);`, so `argv[2]` is `(char*)0x7ffeec636875`

Comment: @ikegami Let's stick to the facts. The question is "How to parse an pointer in string form to int pointer in C?" My answer answers it. Everything else is inconsistent speculation.

Comment: You really think they knew enough to use `snprintf` but not `sscanf`? No, the OP uses the word "string form" because it's a `char*`, not cause the pointer is actually a string. What you say is can only be true if everything else about the question makes absolutely no sense, including what the OP said they did: pass a pointer to `exec`.

Answer (score -1):

You can just cast it to an `int` pointer.

```c
int* ptr = (int*)argv[2];
```

Comment: That presumes the exec call the OP is doing (`execlp(..., matrix1Start, ..., 0)` or similar) actually works. Except `execlp` expects NUL-terminated strings, and the bytes of an integer doesn't form a NUL-terminated string. Even if you were to ensure that a NUL followed it, it's very likely to contain a NUL byte. So while this answers the OP's question, it is useless as an answer because it's usuable.